# error of the model query Mysql and EF6 c# windows forms

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, linq, entity-framework-6

I need help I want to implement an EF6 6.4.4 model with the MySQL / NET 8.0.22 connector generates the model and everything does it fine until I generate a simple query like

```
using (Entities db = new Entities ())
{
var lst = db.table.ToList ();
}
```

When generating this query or any other of select it tells me that the table does not exist but in the EF6 model if it is and looking directly to the server from workbench / phpmyadmin there are all entities

[img of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHqpr.png)
[img of the model example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESQRG.png)

app config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <!--<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.10.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d">
      </provider>-->
      
    <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=8.0.22.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d">
      </provider></providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Buffers" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Memory" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.1" newVersion="4.0.1.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.22.0" newVersion="8.0.22.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Google.Protobuf" publicKeyToken="a7d26565bac4d604" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.14.0.0" newVersion="3.14.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="K4os.Compression.LZ4.Streams" publicKeyToken="2186fa9121ef231d" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.6.0" newVersion="1.2.6.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="BouncyCastle.Crypto" publicKeyToken="0e99375e54769942" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.8.6.0" newVersion="1.8.6.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <connectionStrings>
    
  <add name="arquitectura2Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.Prueba.csdl|res://*/Model.Prueba.ssdl|res://*/Model.Prueba.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=root;database=arquitectura2&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```